# JavaScript: making a dynamic class clickable -- why not working?

Tags: javascript, dom, html, dynamic

The code below creates a button on screen, and when clicked, it creates new Div's dynamically. And after a certain number of clicks it deletes all the newly created Div's.

The problem: I want to make the newly created Div's also clickable so they create new Div's. Why is the following function not working?

```
$('.dynamic').click(function()
```

The complete code is below. Go ahead and try it.

```
   <html>    
    <head>
        <style>
            .dynamic {
                color:blue;
                font-size:18px;
            }
        </style>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.0.js"></script>
    </head>    
    <body>
        <div>
            <button id="master">click this</button>
        </div>
        <script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#master').click(function() {
                    if ($('.dynamic').length > 4) {
                        $('.dynamic').remove();
                    } else {
                        var divCount = Number($('.dynamic').length + 1);
                        $(this).before('<div class="dynamic">Dynamic Div ' + divCount + '</div>');
                    }
                });

                $('.dynamic').click(function() {
                    var divCount = Number($('.dynamic').length + 1);
                    $(this).before('<div class="dynamic">Dynamic Div ' + divCount + '</div>');
                });    
            });
        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: It works http://jsfiddle.net/T3ZbL/

Comment: Nope. The button works, yes. But the dynamically created Div's do not respond to clicks -- op.

Comment: yup, the fiddle doesn't work.

Comment: @user1883050 Yep, misread the question. Put up an answer now I understood it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not working because you're hooking up the event in the document ready *before* the items exist. You need to attach the event to the items after they're created.

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/T3ZbL/4/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#master').click(function () {
        if ($('.dynamic').length > 4) {
            $('.dynamic').remove();
        } else {
            var divCount = Number($('.dynamic').length + 1);
            var newItem = $('<div class="dynamic">')
                .addClass('dynamic')
                .text('Dynamic Div ' + divCount)
                .click(function () {
                    var divCount = Number($('.dynamic').length + 1);
                    $(this).before('<div class="dynamic">Dynamic Div ' + divCount + '</div>');
                });
            $(this).before(newItem);
        }
    });
});
```

Note that the above code does not apply the click even to the items created by clicking on a `.dynamic`, ideally the creation of the new items should be factored out into its own method.

Comment: Thank you genius person. -- op.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) in jQuery for dynamic elements

```
 $(document).on("click","#master",function()..
 .........
```

Comment: This is not an answer or solution to the question, just a suggestion. It works using `.click()`.

Comment: @PSR : Could you enlighten me about the difference between using a `click` handler directly and `on`

Comment: @harsha it is for dynamic elements

Comment: @harsha `on()` is the preferred method now, that is all. Both work currently. click() hasn't even been deprecated yet http://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: @DanielImms your fiddle is not working as expected. .click() does not work with the element created dynamically by javascript.

Comment: @AnkitJaiswal what browser?

Comment: @DanielImms Chrome -- Version 27.0.1453.93

Comment: @AnkitJaiswal I'm on 26 and seems fine.